# Sqldatasource where parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a sqldatasource, in select command i have `@status` parameter. The parameter take the value from the textbox at runtime.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [project_details] WHERE ([status] = @status)" 
            FilterExpression="title='{4}'" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            EnableCaching="True">
 <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="status" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"
                    Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

my problem is that when i run the page without entring the parameter in text box sqldatasource is not returing any row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression.aspx), you have to alter how you have setup the `SqlDataSource`.

Try this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [project_details]" 
        FilterExpression="title='{0}'" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        EnableCaching="True">
    <FilterParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="status" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" Type="String" />
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have removed the `Where` clause from the query as this will be applied by the filter expression. Also, I have changed the filter expression from `title='{4}'` to `title='{0}'`. The documentation states that the number is a placeholder to an item in the FilterParameters collection.

Updated
I have also changed the SelectParameters to FilterParameters

**Update 2**

I have created a working example to finish of this answer. This will filter the Title column using the text from the text box. If this text box is empty it will return all the rows from the table (a scary thought but OK for this example).  It is querying the AdventureWorks database for which I set a connection string called AWorks.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AWorks %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT ContactId, Title, FirstName, LastName FROM Person.Contact"
    FilterExpression="Title='{0}'"
    runat="server">
 <FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Title" ControlID="txtTitle" PropertyName="Text" />
 </FilterParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" Id="txtTitle"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" Text="Submit" />

<asp:GridView 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField Visible="false" DataField="ContactId"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField Visible="true" DataField="Title"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField Visible="true" DataField="FirstName"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField Visible="true" DataField="LastName"></asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: hey thanks but here  i forgot to mention my filter parameter.

Comment: Good point. I have updated the answer and change the SelectParameters to a FilterParameters collection

Comment: i totally agree with you Keith .it should work .but i dont know why even after adding your code it is not working

Comment: conclusion filter expression sucks i am working with where statement to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

set `ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"` and then try....

Answer (score 0):

try a condition like this:

```
(@Status is null or @Status ='' Or Status = @Status)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"` to your SqlDataSource.